# How to get all defects in ClearQuest by HTTP Restful API

Tags: clearquest

This question should be easy if you are familiar with ClearQuest, unfortunately, it's an old tool and there is not much useful resources on the Internet. I only found one article helpful https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/rational/r-cn-rcqoslccmrestapi/index.html

Here is I've already tired, I can get all defects that the state is `Resolved` by this URL http://192.168.0.1/cqweb/oslc/repo/cqdb/db/SAMPL/record/?oslc_cm.query=State="Resolved"&rcm.type=Defect

But there are many different states in ClearQuest, such as `Summitted, Closed, Checked` etc, so how to get all defects in the database, I don't want to try every URL in my code. Is there an another way to do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. This finds the defects of a particular defect family though.

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/?oslc_cm.query=Found_in_Product_Family="MyDefectFamily"&rcm.type=Defect
```

reference :
https://jazz.net/forum/questions/147541/rational-clearquest-http-request-to-find-defects-that-have-been-updated-since-a-specific-time

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know the value of field MyDefectFamily? Here is a table named `FAMILY_MEMBER_DEF` in database, but it's empty.

Comment: Check this.   http://192.168.0.1/cqweb/oslc/repo/cqdb/db/SAMPL/record/?rcm.type=Defect

Comment: It doesn't work, the response says you have to specifiy `rcm.name` or `oslc_cm.query`