# How to know the corresponding url of clearquest web query

Tags: clearquest

after login clearquest web, user can create personal query. I want to use query to export to excel as https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-export-query-rational-clear-quest-web-701v-excel-format describes.

However, I can't find a way to know the url of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57425298/6309), it can be an URL starting with:

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest
# as in
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/?oslc_cm.query=Found_in_Product_Family="MyDefectFamily"&rcm.type=Defect
```

This assume you are using the [ClearQuest OSLC REST interface](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/about-using-lan-clearcasewan-clearquest-ucm-integration-utilizes-clearquest-oslc-rest-interface), knowing that [OSLC 2.0 REST API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.oslc_cmrest_api.doc/topics/c_cq_oslc_rest_api_ovw.htm) is a RESTful (Representational State Transfer) interface that adheres to the **Open Services for Lifecycle Collaboration** (**OSLC**) 2.0 Core and Change Management (CM) specifications.